# merging multiple pdf files into one per file name using PDFtk pro

Tags: pdftk

I have a situation that I need to merge files again by file names. Now, I have files in one folder like this -

A1.pdf,
A2.pdf,
B1.pdf,
C1.pdf,
C2.pdf,
C3.pdf.

The goal is to merge files by file names and I will get A.pdf, B.pdf, C.pdf. I tried different things in the batch file, but none worked so far. Can you please help?

The real files names are like this below.

115_11W0755_70258130_841618403_01.PDF
115_12W0332_70258122_202990692_01.PDF
115_12W0332_70258122_202990692_02.PDF
115_12W0332_70258122_202990692_03.PDF
115_14W0491_70258174_562605608_01.PDF
115_14W0491_70258174_562605608_02.PDF
115_14W0776_70258143_680477806_01.PDF
115_16W0061_70258083_942231888_01.PDF
115_16W0065_70258176_202990692_01.PDF
115_16W0065_70258176_202990692_02.PDF

the 3rd part (70258083) is the element that works as uinque per batch. In other words, I want to merge files per this element. from the file names listed above, there will be 6 PDF files.

I am using the batch script below to merge two files into one. I don't know how to tweak this to more than 2 files to merge OR leave a single file alone.

Please help.

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%# in (115_*.pdf) do (
set n=%%~n#
set n=!n:~,-30!

```
  pdftk A=!n!.pdf B=%%# cat B A output C:\IN\_fileNames\Merge\Files\!n!.pdf
```

)

here is the error screen

[image]

Comment: This is more a batch file loop writing question rather than a pdftk question. You might have more success if you update your tag.